# Reference: Bochner Integral`

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, integration, geometric-probability, random-functions

What would be an easily accessible book dealing with Bochner integration as applied to probability theory (I'm looking to understand random elements and their basic related concepts in a formal yet vaguely conceptual manner).
Preferably, I'm looking for a book that develops everything from scratch (so that i don't miss out on any important conceptual points).

Comment: I don't know about "vaguely conceptual", but Diestel and Uhl's book _Vector Measures_ gives a very thorough approach to the basics.

Comment: Have you seen Bochner integration *at all* and just want to see applications of it in probability theory, or are you asking for a source where you can learn about it with probability theory as the motivating topic?

Comment: The second one mostly

Comment: Hytönen, T. et. al. (2016) [_Analysis in Banach Spaces_](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-48520-1) is a good reference. Its subtitle goes _Volume I: Martingales and Littlewood-Paley Theory_.